# Django OneToOneField relacion multiple

Tags: python, django, django-models

tengo en Django los siguientes 3 modelos:

```
class Article_1 (models.Model):

  title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
  prices = models.OneToOneField("Prices",null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='A1_prices')

class Article_2 (models.Model):

  title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
  prices = models.OneToOneField("Prices",null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='A2_prices')

class Prices(models.Model):

  parent = models.OneToOneField('no se',null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='parent')
  shop1 = models.IntegerField ( null=True, blank=True)
  shop2 = models.IntegerField ( null=True, blank=True)
  shop3 = models.IntegerField ( null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)+"__"+ 'no se'
```

El objetivo es tener una base de datos de una serie de articulos, donde el modulo Prices sea accesible desde cada articulo, y poder asignarle un precio determinado para cada tienda en el que se encuentra. De esta manera tendria un modelo Prices flexible que me permitiria agregar tantas tiendas como quisiera.

El caso es que no se como hacer que parent apunte de forma generica a cualquier articulo desde el que es llamado, para introducir los precios, y retornar un **str** que incluya el id y el title, del articulo desde el que se ha rellenado los precios.

Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 1):

te recomiendo que para los precios puedas utilizar

[DjangoMoney](https://github.com/django-money/django-money). 
Bueno esto funcionaria si tu quieres subir los artículos y las tiendas solo puedan seleccionar esos artículos y darles sus precios personalizados.

```
from djmoney.models.fields import MoneyField


class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)


class StoreArticle(models.Model):
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="articles")
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="shops")
    price = MoneyField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD')
```

Como hago para ver todos los artículos de una tienda, en este ejemplo vamos a suponer que tienes una tienda con el id=1

```
shop = Shop.objects.get(pk=1) # shop = Shop.objects.filter(pk=1).first()
articles = shop.articles.all() # me va traer todos los artículos de esa tienda
```

Ahora quiero ver todas las tiendas que utilizaron(colocaron en su lista) el Articulo que tiene el id=10(ejemplo)

```
article = Article.objects.get(pk=10) # article = Article.objects.filter(pk=10).first()
shops = article.shops.all()
```

Ahora recuerda si quieres que cada tienda pueda subir sus propios artículos

```
class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    price = MoneyField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD')
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="articles")
```